# "Хотите верьте, хотите нет". Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, тире

Речь о поговорке "хотите верьте, хотите нет". Нужны ли тут еще какие-то знаки, например, тире перед "нет"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, больше ничего не надо. Тире перед "нет" не надо, ибо нет никаких условий ("нет" - это сказуемое, так что оно не может быть опущено).

Answer (score 1):

Если бы это выражение не было фразеологизмом, то ***тире, конечно, поставить нужно было бы обязательно***, и не одно, а два.
***1)Если хотите, то верьте, 2)если хотите, то не верьте (нет)***. В этом сложном предложении два сложноподчинённых предложения с придаточными условия. Убираем союзы "если... то", получаем два бессоюзных предложения:***1)Хотите - верьте, 2)хотите - нет.*** Тире необходимо, так как в первом предложении (хотите)содержится условие того, о чём говорится во втором (верьте): верьте (при каком условии?) Аналогично со вторым БСП.
Но это устойчивое словосочетание, поэтому встречается употребление и без тире.

Comment: Эта тема вновь стала предметом дискуссии (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445021/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: А кинокомедию почему-то назвали с тире: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDqvLcmbPeAhXJh6YKHZHtDkcQ_AUIDygC&biw=1536&bih=765#imgrc=iJImwzLTGZuEGM:&spf=1541075559695