# Всегда ли ставится запятая после слова "хотите"?

Tags: пунктуация

Обычно запятая после "хотите" ставится:

(1) Ну, хорошо, ― наконец пожала плечами Марина. ― *Хотите, оставайтесь* так. Только есть будет неудобно. [Андрей Геласимов. Год обмана (2003)]

А почему нет запятой в этом предложении?

(2) Когда позднее всем девушкам предложили ― *хотите оставайтесь* в роте, *хотите уезжайте* на родину, Ольга уехала к матери в Витебск, а Саша остался. [С. М. Голицын. Записки беспогонника (1946-1976)]

Comment: В Нацкорпусе, похоже, нашелся только один такой пример. Думаю, просто ошибка.

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445007/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5

Comment: Не похоже, что там ошибка. Вряд ли еще пара запятых "украсила" бы текст, да и произношение тоже без паузы. Обратите внимание на  одно, а не два тире,  значит, это не вставная конструкция. Всё придаточное предложение читается как одно целое, нет возможности для деления её на части.

Comment: Вот ещё пример без запятой: Что хотите делайте. Но здесь устойчивый оборот. А в ответе на вопрос (по ссылке) не указана грамматика предложения: сложное бессоюзное - не похоже; может быть, первое предложение вводное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая после **хотите** ставится не всегда. Наиболее известное употребление без запятой, кроме упомянутых устойчивых "где (как, когда и т.п.) хотите ...", встречается в выражении "хотите верьте, хотите нет".

При подобном противопоставлении пауза между **хотите** и последующим глаголом уменьшается вплоть до полного отсутствия. В добротных изданиях можно найти аналогичные выражения с противопоставлением, хотя искать их сложно из-за обилия более типичных фраз. Приведу один пример из журнала "Известия. Серия общественных наук", 1960 г.

> ... что якобы здесь сказано от бакинцев хотите приезжайте сюда, не хотите вовсе не приезжайте...

**Дополнение**.
Добавлю ещё пару цитат известных авторов. (Также считаю, что переводы известных авторов обычно проходят качественную корректуру, особенно в полных собраниях сочинений).

> "Хотите пейте, хотите не пейте" (Надежда Тэффи, Юмористические рассказы, в нескольких разных изданиях). Эта же фраза встречается в книгах других авторов с такой же пунктуацией.
>
> "...Хотите слушайте, не хотите не надо" (Генрих Сенкевич, Полное собрание сочинений, 1907)

PS. Хороший вопрос! Но сложный — мой ответ не проясняет его в достаточной мере.

Comment: Вот мнение учителя (@ЕкатеринаКаштанова) : "хотите верьте, хотите нет" — исключение, потому что фразеологизм, во всех остальных случаях нужно ставить знаки препинания:   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: А кинокомедию почему-то назвали с тире: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDqvLcmbPeAhXJh6YKHZHtDkcQ_AUIDygC&biw=1536&bih=765#imgrc=iJImwzLTGZuEGM:&spf=1541075559695

Comment: @М_Г Я встречал сотни цитат подобной конструкции и с тире, и с запятыми. Тоже в добротных изданиях. Но я отвечаю на другой вопрос.